# How to import specific files from a large list in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to import only 357 specific csv files from a folder with over 2,000 large files. I have a separate list called "names" with just the 357 files I want to analyze:

```
names$list_id = paste(list_id, 'csv', sep = '.')
names <- as.list(names)
```

The names now look like this: 987.123.456.csv, 987.123.457.csv....

I know how to import all the files at once and combine them into a single file with the code:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)read.table(x, h=T))
D = do.call("rbind", datalist)
```

But I don't want to import all 2,000+ giant files. Is it possible to read just the select files from my list of names that I want into R using a loop?

I am hoping to have just a single file with all the data from just the 357 files I have already filtered and selected. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you have the list of files you could select the ones you want using [[ ]], passing the right positions of the files you want. could it work or your case?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. At some point you have a list with the names of the files, say names, if you only want to import files 1, 10 and 20 why wouldn't you call the loading function over names[c(1,10,20)]?

Comment: Because there are 357 'random' files and they are not in order. Also, where would I call the loading function over names? I am not sure where that would go in my code.

Comment: I was referring to this part: `datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)read.table(x, h=T))
D = do.call("rbind", datalist)` But those random files are named, right? your could call the files you want to import just those. `filelist = paste(c(987, 123 , 456), ".csv", sep = "")` instead of creating a list with all the names to select only the ones you want

Comment: I have updated my question. Hopefully that clarify things. I don't want to have to individually call all 357 names. I would like to just use the list I have created to do that.

Comment: How woul it work if you pass names instead of filelist in your code? would it call only the names of the specific files you want and not the 2.000 files?

Comment: It doesn't work when I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if this work.

I'll assume you're in the folder where all the files are and that you only want to import
the files 1.csv, 10.csv, 20.csv and 40.csv

```
library(dplyr)

selected_files_to_import <- paste(c(1,10, 20, 40), ".csv", sep = "")

list_of_data_frame <- lapply(selected_files_to_import, function(x){
  read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = F)
})

aggregated_df <- bind_rows(list_of_data_frame)
```

Another solution could be

```
library(purrr)

selected_files_to_import <- paste(c(1,10, 20, 40), ".csv", sep = "")

aggregated_df <- map_df(selected_files_to_import,
       ~ read.csv(., stringsAsFactors = F))
```

selected_files_to_import is the vector with the files names. You could replace this part whith the list you already have.

Comment: thanks, I'll edit the answer. I was prefering bind_rows over rbind in case variables names change (i.e. uppercase, lowecase) in that case rbind will throw an error

Comment: Yes, this works with just a slight modification. Thank you!